# How do I save the coordinates and image onto a integer variable?

Tags: java, arrays

For my project, I need to be able to place an image, then have the coordinates x, y and the image name be "saved" onto a integer. The integer is then placed into an array. So if the array gets called up, it will give an image name and integer coordinates.

```
    sticker [] placedsticker = new sticker [20];
    int slot = 0;
    int placedpic;
    else if (bluntSoundPlay){ //else if bluntSound is true
        EZ.addImage("blunt.png", clickX, clickY); //a blunt will be placed
        bluntsound.play(); //and blunt sound will play
        placedpic = 0;//each image has a different placed picnumber. ex. 0, 1, 2, 3.
        slot ++;//int slot increments every time image is placed so if it is at 1, it will fill in slot 0 of the array. If slot is 2 it will fill in slot 1 of the array.
                }
```

How would I save all this information to the placedpic integer? And also, how would I put slot 1 into array slot 0?

Comment: Is that what is used to save everything onto a variable/integer?

Comment: What does that even mean? saving everything into an Integer!

Comment: If you or anyone else can figure out how to store an image into a 32 bit integer and afterwards restore it, I will pay good money ;) Please clarify the requirements of your assignment.

Comment: Did you not read it? I want to save the "coordinates and image" onto an integer to be put into an array.

Comment: An `int[][]` maybe. Just an `int` is pushing it!

Comment: @user5329697 You can't store an image name in an `int` either. An `int` only takes up `32` bits, whereas an image name (a `String`) is likely to require a lot more memory. I think you need to clarify your question. What does putting slot `1` into array slot `0` mean?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant to say you would like to save an image name and coordinates in an array. As opposed to saving them in an integer in an array.

You could have a SortedSet of (ImageName, X, Y) and then simple add that object to array? Is this what you're trying to achieve?

You would first create an Object to hold your data:

```
class ImageData {
    public String name;
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public ImageData(String name, int x, int y) {
        this.name = name;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Then add them to a list:

```
Vector v = Vector();
ImageData image = ImageData("cat.jpg", 0, 0);
v.add(image);
```

Comment: I had something like this `sticker [] placedsticker = new sticker [20]; ` to hold my data. It creates 20 spaces where I can store my information.

Comment: @user5329697 And your `sticker` has fields for your image name, x coordinate and y coordinate?

Comment: This is my sticker class. `public class sticker {

 EZImage image;
 int x=-100;//places the image off screen
 int y=-100;
 EZSound sound;
 String imageName;
  sticker(String fileName, String newSound, int newX, int newY){                
   image = EZ.addImage(fileName,x,y);
   imageName = fileName;
   setPosition(newX,newY);
   sound = EZ.addSound(newSound);
  }
  void setPosition(int newX,int newY){
   x = newX;
   y = newY;
   image.translateTo(newX, newY);
  }      
  int getXPosition(){
   return x;
  }
  int getYPosition(){
   return y;
  }
}
`

Comment: And also, what is Vector?

Comment: Vector is similar to an array, it's another method of storing objects.